# Controlling a Motor with a Raspberry and a Joystick

Tags: pi-2, pwm

I'm realizing a little embedded system with a Raspberry Pi 2 for controlling a dc motor using an analog joystick. 
In particular i'm using a [PCF8591](http://www.sunfounder.com/ad-da-converter-pcf8591-module.html) as adc to read the joystick and a [L298N](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CAG6GX2) to drive the motor. After some tests I have successfully controlled the motor using wiringPi library, the only problem I found was about response time of the whole system, if I don't add some delays into the code the response time is very long and variable. 
Adding some delays things seems to be better, in particular I have achieved a 1.3s resposne time with a delay of 1000 in main and 300 in reading function, lowering those delays I can have a better response time but it wasn't really "real-time", some suggestion?

What can cause those delay in the system? How and when i should put delays in the code?

Comment: You are going to need to share the code here for any actual help to occur.

Comment: Are you using software PWM or hardware PWM to control the motors?